# How do I configure Apache2 correctly for Websockets SSL (wss)?

Tags: websocket, apache2

I have an application and soketi.app webserver hosted in AWS.  The applications are served behind a load balancer.  I can access the application just fine (443 traffic is forwarded to the instance on port 8788).  I'm having problems talking to the soketi server via wss (SSL) protocol with error: Could not connect to wss://mydomain.com/6001/app/blahblah

My goal is to configure Apache as a websocket proxy instead of establishing an SSL connection between the browser and my websocket server.

Apache2 **000-default.conf** (necessary apache mods are installed and enabled):

```
<VirtualHost *:8788>
       ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
       DocumentRoot /var/www/public/
       <Directory />
           Options FollowSymLinks
           AllowOverride None
       </Directory>
       <Directory /var/www/public/>
            Options All
            AllowOverride All
            order allow,deny
            allow from all
        </Directory>
       ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

       LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:6001>
ProxyPass /app ws://127.0.0.1:6001/app
ProxyPassReverse /app ws://127.0.0.1:6001/app
</VirtualHost>
```

**soketi-config.json**

```
{
    "debug": true,
    "appManager.array.apps": [
        {
            "id": "blah",
            "key": "blah",
            "secret": "blah"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution came down to 2 things:

- The websocket server (soketi.app) I have hosted in the cloud uses port 6001 by default.  This port is actually used (for quite a long time) by another application called X11.  Simply changing the port is a matter of configuration.
- The basic idea of not directly establishing an SSL connection between the browser and the websocket server, but rather use Apache as a proxy.
  This can also be done with nginx but I use apache.

My app consists of 2 containers in the cloud and they sit behind a load balancer. App container uses port 8788.  Websockets container uses port 56112.

**ports.conf**

```
Listen 8788
Listen 56112

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

**000-default.conf**

Proxies websocket (wss) requests to websocket server running locally (ws) on port 56113

```
<VirtualHost *:8788>
       ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
       DocumentRoot /var/www/public/
       <Directory />
           Options FollowSymLinks
           AllowOverride None
       </Directory>
       <Directory /var/www/public/>
            Options All
            AllowOverride All
            order allow,deny
            allow from all
        </Directory>
       ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

       # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
       # alert, emerg.
       LogLevel warn

       # CustomLog /var/log/apache2/rest-api.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:56112>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLProxyEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/blah.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/blah.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/chain.crt

  ProxyRequests on
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "http"
  ProxyPass /app http://localhost:56112/
  ProxyPassReverse /app http://localhost:56112/

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
  RewriteRule .* ws://localhost:56113%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
</VirtualHost>
```